# Notepad++ Language Definition : Highlight line ending with ":" Character

Tags: regex, notepad++, autohotkey

I am currently using AutoHotKey, and I'm using lots of sub-functions. And so, in Notepad++, I would like to define a style for lines ending with ":".

An example of this situation would be :

```
FillGroup:
    Gosub, GetID
    Send, sometext {Down} {Enter}
Return
```

(FillGroup would be in blue, for example)

Even though I'm kind of a newbie to it, I tried some Regex in the Open delimiter section(I tried `.+:` and `.+:$`), but without conclusive results.

Comment: What about `(.+:)$` ?

Comment: No, it doesnt work either

Comment: Maybe this works? `(^.+\:$)` and make sure you don't allow the dot to match line breaks. Alternatively this might work: `(^[^\:]+\:$)`. I don't know how exactly notepad++ handles the regex. So the parentheses may or may not be required. And I'm not entirely sure if [colons](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Readability_enhancements) require escaping.

Comment: @Druzion I'm pretty sure UDL doesn't support regex

Comment: See, i've read in some place that it does support regex, and some place that it doesn't. I think it supports regex only in the search & replace field, that may be why i'm confused. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, and until proven wrong, there is no (clean) way to do this since UDL 2.0 doesn't support regex.

You may brute force it by setting all the possible values of the opening within `(( ))` and separated by a space and the `end` with something like `:((EOL))`

Comment: I have way too many values to handle it this way. I thought UDL supported regex, but I just figured it's only the search&replace in notepad that does support it. Thanks for the help, I guess that for now it is impossible to do what I want.